# Is Damage Considered an Effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, simultaneous-effects

Do the rules for Combining Game & Spell Effects apply to damage? A player argued that damage wasn't an effect so the rules regarding "Combining Game & Magical Effects" didn't apply.  This was in regard to spell damage from multiple Moonbeams cast on different tiles of a large creature where the areas don't overlap.

The following is defined under "Conditions"

> Conditions alter a creature's capabilities in a variety of ways and can arise as a result of a spell, a class feature, a monster's attack, or other effect.
>
> If multiple Effects impose the same condition on a creature, each instance of? the condition has its own Duration, but the condition’s Effects don’t get worse. A creature either has a condition or doesn’t.

The following are the rules on Combining Effects.

PHB ("Combining Magical Effects"):

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect--such as the highest bonus--from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.

DMG ("Combining Game Effects"):

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe this wouldn't fall under common usage, or dictionary definition? What do you need?

Comment: A player argued that damage wasn't an effect so the rules regarding "Combining Game & Magical Effects" didn't apply.

Comment: @SeanCulligan Perhaps "Do the rules for *Combining Game & Spell Effects* apply to damage?" would be a better question. Or "Is damage considered an effect?" but that one probably still falls under "how English speakers use it." Either way, details regarding the situation could be helpful. What specific rules came into conflict with your player?

Comment: Consider asking about a question that *isn't* this totally fine as-is question but is *instead* about whether damage is an effect in a new question, since that's what it would be

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I took your advise and changed the wording of the question.

Comment: @SeanCulligan Is this related to moon beam, or another situation?

Comment: @Sean Culligan   Here  is a related topic which might help: [How do the rules on Combining Game Effects and Combining Magical Effects relate to damage types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162798/how-do-the-rules-on-combining-game-effects-and-combining-magical-effects-relate)

Comment: @SeanCulligan please describe the situation where it does matter. There might be a specific ruling, not a common rule.

Comment: I don't understand what the question here is. At what point does 'damage is an effect' come into play, exactly? How and when do you take multiple instances of damage at the same time?

Comment: I agree with @enkryptor; it sounds like we need the specific situation that prompted the player to make this case as an example, and the player's argument _in the context of this specific situation_. As it stands, this looks like it might be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But if we can get the "Y" from you, rather than the "X" that we currently have, I don't see why we couldn't reopen this at that point...

Comment: With this update, it seems like a duplicate of [your previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163651/if-two-moonbeam-spells-are-placed-on-a-large-creature-does-it-take-damage-from). WHat's different?

Comment: I agree; having the specifics is helpful, but I wasn't anticipating this exact outcome when I wrote my previous comment. For this question to have any purpose, what answer were you expecting to get for this question that the other question doesn't already give you? Is it that you just don't like the answers of the other question?

Answer (score 6):

### There is no D&D specific definition

So [it takes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135039/what-is-the-source-for-5e-defaulting-to-plain-english-readings-of-non-game-terms) its normal English one:

> something that inevitably follows an antecedent (such as a cause or agent)

([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect))

Answer (score 2):

## Damage is an effect, not a feature

Combining game effects says:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more **game features have the same name**, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again

Damage *has* to be a game effect. It has rules and consequences in the game but it is not a feature. It isn't a feature because it has no name such as Fire Form or Acid Arrow and therefore the rule state above can't apply. Not only is it not a feature, but there is no way to ever have 2 simultaneous attacks (that I know of), all attacks are consecutive (save for a select few spells).

Comment: @NautArch I'm suggesting the opposite. For the Combining Game Effect to apply the game features need the same name. I'm saying that weapon attacks have no name and therefore can't have that rule applied to them. Is there a way I can clear this up in my answer?

Comment: Maybe saying just that...or wait until OP clarifies exactly what they're trying to ask.

Comment: Specifically damage from spells such as multiple Moonbeams cast on the corners of large (or larger) creatures.

Comment: @SeanCulligan Isn't that a question you've already asked? In that case combining magic effects *does* take effect because they share a name and duration (if they're affecting the same creature at the same time)

Comment: Yes, I asked the question regarding Moonbeam earlier and the response was split 50/50.  My player agreed with the rules on combining magic effect however he claimed that damage is not an effect.  I could find nothing to refute that so I figured I would ask the experts here.